# PHP Script is not running via cron job

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I have a php script that queries a MySQL and IBM Informix database (located in other host), generates json files, handles the information and inserts it into the MySQL database.

The script has a main file and another that has the query handling functions. Staying like this:

```
/opt/project
     script.php
     functions.php
```

The script.php requires the functions.php file, generate json where is being executed based on queries to databaes, and inserts the data handled.

I can run the script smoothly using absolute or relative path.

Inside /opt/project:

```
# php script.php
```

Somewhere else:

```
 # /usr/bin/php /opt/project/scrpt.php
```

However, when its executed by cron job, doesn't work. I did already set up informing environment variables, performed log tests, and even created a shell script to run script.php with cron running the shell script.

Server PATH (CentOS 7): /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/IBM/informix/bin

Crontab contents tried:

```
SHELL=/usr/local/bin
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/IBM/informix/bin
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /opt/project/script.php
```

With root ahead command:

```
SHELL=/usr/local/bin
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/IBM/informix/bin
* * * * * root /usr/bin/php /opt/project/script.php
```

Changing directory:

```
SHELL=/usr/local/bin
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/IBM/informix/bin
* * * * * cd /opt/project && /usr/bin/php script.php
```

Cron to run shell script instead php directly:

```
SHELL=/usr/local/bin   
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/IBM/informix/bin
* * * * * cd /opt/project && sh run_script.sh
```

Where shell script has the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /opt/project

PHP=`which php`
$PHP script.php
```

The cron logs didn't show anything wrong, and if I redirect the output to a file it's create the file, but didn't run the php script, even by shell script to do that. I tried with not set SHELL and PATH in the crontab, but doesn't work too.

Comment: Set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`. Also remove this `which php` and instead invokevusing `/usr/bin/env php script`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I did test and didn't work. The script doesn't has error. Even set the shebang and invoking with absolute path, './opt/project/script.php', the cron jog was called but the script was not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the variables of the SDK to connect with IBM Infomix database. Although I had set the PATH, it was necessary to export the environment variables from IBM Informix that I define when I did install the Informix SDK. The strange was that even with the PDO exeptions no one error was generate when I redirect error standard output with &>.

May exist an most elegant way to do that but I can't play with live environment. Follow that cron job that currently works:

```
SHELL=/usr/local/bin
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/IBM/informix/bin
14,29,44,59 * * * * root export INFORMIXSERVER=<data_source_name> && export INFORMIXDIR=<path_to_informix_sdk> && export INFORMIXTMP=<path_infomix_tmp> && export INFORMIXSQLHOSTS=<path_to_sqlhost_file> && export $PATH:$INFORMIXDIR/bin && /usr/bin/php /opt/project/script.php &> /var/log/project/task.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
* * * * * /full/path/to/your/run_script.sh
```

instead:

```
* * * * * cd /opt/project && sh run_script.sh
```

if you want your bash or sh script to be executed the path to the script should be absolute path as above or:

```
./run_script.sh
```

note the `./`. otherwise the script will not be executed.

also make your bash script exectuable by:

```
chmod +x run_script.sh
```

you may also run the script directly without `run_script.sh` from cron:

```
* * * * * /absolute/path/to/php -f "/absolute/path/to/script.php"
```

for changing current directory to the one that your php script sits in you may use this at the beginning of your php script:

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
```

because when you run php script by cron then the current dir for php is not the script but different (due to the fact it was started by cron)

Comment: I made the changes. I checked that setting chdir wherever the script path is executed will be where the script is. The cron job is executed, I can see the logs, if I put some output in shell script the file with content is created, but the run scrpt.php by shell or directly set it in the crontab -e doesn't work. I did already set cron job under /etc/init.d and right in /etc/crontab, with root ahead command.

Comment: if I set a cron job to out put my cron environment I see the PATH and SHELL variables as I set before the job.

Comment: @LeandroArruda have you tried `/absolute/path/to/php -f "/absolute/path/to/script.php"` ? what was the result?

Comment: Yes. I put with double quotes. The script works manually, I'm set cron jobs with root user.